# Vibrate device on long button press

Tags: android, android-vibration

I want the device to vibrate as long as the user clicks the button. If the user press the button for a long period of time the device is to vibrate as long as the user clicks and holds. here is what I implemented but it works for a particular period of time.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {   

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if(v==button){
            Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vb.vibrate(1000);
       }                
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vibrate indefinitelly you can use vibration pattern:

```
// 0 - start immediatelly (ms to wait before vibration)
// 1000 - vibrate for 1s
// 0 - not vibrating for 0ms
long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 0};
vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

Vibration can be cancelled using:

```
vb.cancel();
```

Start vibration on [onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) event - [`ACTION_DOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN), stop vibration on [`ACTION_UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP)

**EDIT:** final working code:

```
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 0};
                    vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    vb.cancel();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you plese suggest what is wrong in my code here      final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {  
Vibrator vb = (Vibrator)   getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);  
@Override  
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
switch (event.getAction()){  
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
// put your code here   
long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 0};  
vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);  
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
vb.cancel();  
break; 
}  
return false;  
}  
});  
}

Comment: I've noticed missing break in case ACTION_DOWN (so the vibration is cancelled immediately)

Answer (score 1):

implement ontouch listener and perform this action in event down

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    //int action = event.getAction();
    switch (event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       // put your code here


    break;
```

Comment: Thanks anddevvmanu : but how do i perform vibration if user clicks and holds button for long period of time.the device is to vibrate continuously in this scenario.

Comment: have you tried with this code with this event this gives action until you up your finger. so if you press for long time you receive the event of finger pressed

Answer (score 0):

**In Kotlin:**

You can call the `performHapticFeedback` method on the view reference you obtained by binding

```kotlin
binding.root.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.CONFIRM)
```

Not required vibration permission, you can see other cosntants [HapticFeedbackConstants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants)